# I need sql query for getting the Required format

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

i am having table Category with the columns like
`id(AutoIncrement),Parent_id,Level,Name`

initially for level 1 datas has Parent_id is 0. autoincrement id will be Parent_id for next levels .my table table table datas will bw like this

```
id     Parent_id    Level    Name
1       0             1      Indian
2       0             1      International
3       0             1      Nri
4       1             2      BC 
5       2             2      Christian
6       2             2      Muslim
7       4             3      MBC-1
8       7             4      OBC-2
9       1             2      FC
```

i want to show records in this format (its like a tree view)

```
id     Parent_id    Level    Name
1       0             1      Indian
4       1             2      BC 
7       4             3      MBC-1
8       7             4      OBC-2
9       1             2      FC
5       2             2      Christian
6       2             2      Muslim
2       0             1      International
3       0             1      Nri
4       1             2      BC
```

Can any one should help me to get this arrangement of datas using sql Query?

Comment: There is no recursive query in mysql.

Comment: Can you explain your desire arrangement ? i don't understand it. I have an ideea for a query... but i can't understand your ideea

Comment: @user966875: Is there a finite number of levels in your structure, or could it potentially be unlimited?

Answer (score 0):

If it does not have a set number of branches you likely want to loop over a query in your app or write an SP to obtain all nodes. Some good reading here:
http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/